# retarget_bvh addon actions working using GUI but not using script

Tags: python, add-on, motion-capture, bvh

I want to use the [diffeomorphic BVH retargeter](https://diffeomorphic.blogspot.com) Blender addon to animate Makehuman Characters.

**Using the buttons in the Blender GUI to perform the actions I want works perfectly fine**, but using the according Blender scripting commands does not.

I specifically want to import and retarget the bvh:

```
bpy.ops.mcp.load_and_retarget(filepath=FILEPATH)
```

It **executes without error but seems to do nothing** (Does not add the animation to the character).
So I tried to just import the bvh and see if at least that is working:

```
bpy.ops.mcp.load_bvh(filepath=FILEPATH)
```

But here the rig/animation is not added as an object, but when using the "load BVH" button in GUI it is added.
**So my question is:** Am I doing something wrong here, do I maybe misunderstand [how to use the commands](https://diffeomorphic.blogspot.com/p/mcp-operators.html)?

I am using Blender version 2.93 and retarget_bvh version 2.0. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This Q&A web site can only help with problems using Blender and its built-in addons. That's a third-party addon so you should ask questions about it on the addon's website particularly as you're using an old version of blender.